# 'class' keyword in function signature - is it standard C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, parameters

I'm studying code given to me and I see:

```
AFPSGameMode::AFPSGameMode(const class FPostConstructInitializeProperties& PCIP)
    : Super(PCIP) {   }
```

I'm specially curious about the use of the `class` keyword. Is this standard C++ and if so what does it mean?

Thank you.

Comment: it simply means that the type of the const reference is `FPostConstructInitializeProperties`

Comment: The `class` keyword isn't used usually, but allowed here AFAIR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `class` keyword is allowed here, it's just rare to see it placed here since it can either be completely omitted (if this class has been previously declared) or replaced with the *forward declaration*:

```
void foo(const class FPostConstructInitializeProperties& p){ ... }
```

which is equivalent to:

```
class FPostConstructInitializeProperties; // <-- forward declaration
void foo(const FPostConstructInitializeProperties& p){ ... }
```

Don't get confused with the weird naming conventions. The snippet you have provided expresses something like this:

```
class B{
public:
    B(){ }
    B(const B& b){ };
};

class A{
public:
    B my_b;
    A(const class B& b) : my_b(b) { }  // <-- class keyword in ctor's param decl.
};
```

that could be used for example like this (but I guess it's clear enough already):

```
int main() {
    B b;
    A a(b);
}
```

Comment: It can be omitted if `class FPostConstructInitializeProperties` has been previously declared, but not otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Good point that it can be used as an alternative to forward declaration.

Comment: +1 unicorns for the edited version!

Answer (score 1):

As it was old C, if you have struct say,

```
struct account
{
int field;
..
};
```

You can use it for creating its variables (*objects*) like,

`account obj;`

or,

`struct account obj;`.

Same is for `class`, you may use it, or avoid it. But it is usually not used, but permitted.

Comment: In C, Without a `typedef`, you actually *have to* use the second form. (Don't know about C99 though)

Comment: @lethal-guitar, still the same in C99